# Can I redirect output of a program to gvim?

Tags: vim

I want to redirect the output of some Windows program directly to gvim basically for searching the output. Say for example the result of findstr cmd. Is it possible to do this without dumping it to a file and subsequently loading that file in gvim?

Answer (score 87, accepted):

sure:

```
dir | gvim -
```

the `-` option tells `vim` to open `stdin`

This works for Windows and Linux versions.

Comment: Wow. Must remember this. Cheers Nathan

Comment: @AndresRiofrio: I believe it doesn't.

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10311254/how-does-gvim-work-with-remote) for more information on how to get similar behaviour while using `--remote`.

Comment: Just in case people came here from searching whether this also works for MacVim - yes, it does. `echo 'Testing' | mvim -`

Comment: Thanx, I was looking for something like that now I have a function for passing the program output to file and terminal:
! xterm -e "node % | gvim -" 
for js files - now I can even save the output :) Nifty!

Comment: Is this behaviour broken after the last Windows 10 update?

Comment: @cwschmidt I think it was broken by the batch file changing (or perhaps simple the way Windows pipes into batch files) at some point recently, as spelling out the path to gvim.exe still works fine. It continues to work with vim, curiously.

Comment: @dash-tom-bang The problem went away here, after updating from gvim 7.4 to gvim 8.1

Answer (score 23):

If you're already in Vim you can use the `r` command to read like this:

```
:r !<cmd>
```

E.g.

```
:r !dir
```

Answer (score 3):

You can read it from vim with

```
:r !dir (for example)
```

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, there is no gvim on Mac OS.

If you are using MacVim on mac, this is what I do:

```
dir | /Applications/MacVim.app/Contents/MacOS/Vim -
```

When Vim starts in the terminal, then type

```
<esc>:gui
```

That should start the MacVim (gui version of vim)