# How do I redirect output into Gvim as a list of files to be opened?

Tags: windows, vim, findstr

I would like `findstr /m background *.vim | gvim` to open all `*.vim` files containing `background` in a single instance of gvim - but I can't get the piping to work.

This is very similar to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/856372/can-i-redirect-output-of-a-program-to-gvim) but instead of capturing the stdin output I would like GViM to treat the output as a list of files to be opened - and on a Windows system so xargs isn't guaranteed.  Any ideas?

Comment: There's also this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/437262/how-to-open-a-file-in-a-list-of-files-in-vim, but the accepted solution isn't working for me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I can think of a few ways of doing this:

### Use vimgrep

Use vimgrep: after running gvim, enter:

```
:vimgrep /background/ **/*.vim
```

This will populate the quickfix list with all of the matches (possibly more than one per file), so you can use things like `:copen`, `:cw`, `:cn` etc to navigate (see `:help quickfix`)

---

### Use vim's built-in cleverness

Use `findstr` to give you a list of files and then get vim to open those files:

```
findstr /m background *.vim > list_of_files.txt
gvim list_of_files.txt

" In Gvim, read each file into the buffer list:
:g/^/exe 'badd' getline('.')

" Open the files in tabs:
:bufdo tabedit %
```

This will load each file, but will keep the list of files open as well (you can always bunload it or whatever).

**Edit**:

Using `:tabedit` on a list of files didn't work (I'd only tested `:badd`).  You can get round this by either using badd and then bufdo (as above) or by doing something like this (put it in your vimrc):

```
command! -range=% OpenListedFiles <line1>,<line2>call OpenListedFiles()

function! OpenListedFiles() range
    let FileList = getline(a:firstline, a:lastline)
    for filename in FileList
        if filereadable(filename)
            exe 'tabedit' filename
        endif
    endfor
endfunction
```

Then simply open the file containing all of your required file names and type:

```
:OpenListedFiles
```

---

### Use Vim's server functionality and some awful batch scripting

Use the server functionality and some batch script magic (which I don't understand as I use bash)

```
@echo off
REM Welcome to the hideous world of Windows batch scripts
findstr /m background *.vim > list_of_files.txt
REM Run GVIM (may not be required)
gvim
REM Still in command prompt or .bat file here
REM for each line in the file "list_of_files.txt", pass the line to OpenInTab
for /f %%i in (list_of_files.txt) do call:OpenInTab %%i
goto:eof

:OpenInTab
REM Open the file in a separate tab of an existing vim instance
gvim --remote-tab %~1
goto:eof
```

Eeeurrgh.

---

If it were me, I would go with the "Use vim's built-in cleverness" option.  Actually, that's not true: I'd use cygwin's bash script and just use bash, but if I HAD to do it with the native tools, I'd use the built-in cleverness approach.

Comment: So far I like using the vim's built-in cleverness option...but findstr output is in relative paths and vim needs the absolute path to open the file - how can I preprend the current directory findstr's output?

Comment: How about :%s/\v(.*)/$ESCAPED_DIR\1/g, where $ESCAPED_DIR would be the path to the appropriate directory (including a final path separator) with path separators escaped with backslashes (e.g. C:\\path\\to\\pwd\\)? (The \v turns on super-magical behaviour of regex special characters.)

Comment: Vim shouldn't need the absolute path as long as the path is relative to the directory you're in.  Therefore, you could do `:cd common_path` before running the `:g` command.  If you want to change the paths, simply do `:%s@^@C:/path/to/folder/@` (vim can cope with forward slashes and it saves having to escape the path).

Comment: Note also that if list_of_files.txt is in the "common path" location, you can do `:cd %:p:h` to change to the common path.

Comment: Thanks for the help on this.  From the batch script I can also issue this vim command `-c "lcd %CD%"` and that seems to work just find.  My problem is now with the `:g/^/exe 'tabedit' getline('.')` command.  It only seems to work with the top most file.  Any ideas?

Comment: It seems that the first `tabedit` stops the `:g` command from running.  I've modified the description above to add a couple of (tested) alternatives.

Answer (score 5):

In bash:

```
grep -l background *.vim | xargs gvim
```

The key is `xargs`. It takes lines from standard input and passes them as command line arguments. `grep -l` just prints file names with matches.

---

Another idea, if you don't have `xargs` and cannot download them, then you can transform lines into vim commands (`:edit filename`) and make vim execute them, i.e. open all files. Again, in my environment, where I have `sed`:

```
grep -l background *.vim | sed 's/^/:edit /' > files
vim -s files
```

Even if you don't have `sed`, you can probably replace it with `vi -e` (`ed`).

Comment: Again thanks but I'm looking for dos specific solutions; grep and xargs are not available to me and downloading them is not an option.

Comment: I didn't notice dos tag. Sorry.

Comment: Another idea with vim -s. It needs a temporary file though. And also sed or some ed magic (ed is part of vi, so you surely have it).

Comment: Doing this with vim could mess up your terminal.  I would suggest

    gvim $(grep -l background *.vim)

Answer (score 4):

Open up Powershell:

```
gvim $(findstr /m background *.vim)
```

Comment: Thanks but powershell isn't an option.  I need a solution with barebones dos.

Answer (score 0):

Any of these will open a separate instance of `gvim` with each filename --  particularly useful if there is just one filename but does work for multiple filenames provided you are ok with multiple instances of gvim:

**1) findstr within for**

```
for /f "delims=" %f in ('findstr /m background *.vim') do gvim "%f"
```

**2) pipe findstr to for**

```
findstr /m background *.vim | for /f "delims=" %f in ('more') do gvim "%f"
```

**3) .bat file** Create a file called `gvim_stdin.bat`, say, containing this single line as in (2) except the % signs are doubled:

```
for /f "delims=" %%f in ('more') do gvim "%%f"
```

and then run:

```
findstr /m background *.vim | gvim_stdin
```