# Open list of files in a single Vim instance in single line command

Tags: powershell, vim

I want to open a set of files in a single vim window.  This works:

```
$list = gci *.py -recurse
& gvim.exe $list
```

But this does not (it just gives me an empty vim window):

```
gci *.py -recurse | gvim.exe
```

How can this be done in a single line? It would also be helpful to know why my second method didn't work.

Comment: I don't know the powershell syntax, with shell, you can do something like  `vim $(gci *.py -recurse)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run `Get-ChildItem` in an expression:

```
& gvim.exe (gci *.py -Recurse)
```

Your second statement probably doesn't do anything, because `gvim.exe` doesn't seem to read filenames from STDIN ([related](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1958719/1630171)).

Comment: Well, I did a search before asking the question but didn't see the link you posted.  Thanks for the answer!